# How to set base url for swagger with flask_restplus?

Tags: python, swagger-ui, flask-restplus

I'm serving a flask app with `flask_restplus` from an apache server. I'm using `ProxyPass` to forward all traffic to the app at some url extension like so in the apache `.conf` file:

```
ProxyPass /some-extension http://127.0.0.1:3000
ProxyPassReverse /some-extension http://127.0.0.1:3000
```

The `flask_restplus` api is set up as follows:

```
from flask_restplus import Api
api = Api(
    title='App Title',
    doc='/docs'
)
```

The app works ok except that when I go to the swagger route `/some-extension/docs` the flask server starts looking for swagger dependencies at the url base /swaggerui/ (rather than the required `/some-extension/swaggerui`), and so the swagger UI fails to load.

Is there a way to configure `flask_restplus` (or otherwise) so that swagger gets served `/some-extension/swaggerui/` (rather than the root url)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, got there after some fiddling. You need to proxy traffic on to the extension and set up a flask with a blueprint so the whole app also runs from that extension. So something like this in your apache config:

```
ProxyPass /some-extension http://127.0.0.1:3000/some-extension
ProxyPassReverse /some-extension http://127.0.0.1:3000/some-extension
```

...and you have to ProxyPass the extension /swaggerui like so in your apache configuration:

```
ProxyPass /swaggerui http://127.0.0.1:3000/swaggerui
ProxyPassReverse /swaggerui http://127.0.0.1:3000/swaggerui
```

...and then use this pattern in your `flask_restplus` set up (from [official guide](https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/swagger.html#swagger-ui)):

```
from flask import Flask, Blueprint
from flask_restplus import Api

app = Flask(__name__)
blueprint = Blueprint('api', __name__, url_prefix='/some-extension')
api = Api(blueprint, doc='/docs/')
app.register_blueprint(blueprint)
```